# Can I embed an PApplet in Java FX

Tags: user-interface, arduino, javafx-2, javafx, processing

I am making software whose one part is in [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29). Now I need to develop a GUI for it. But Processing redraws the whole GUI again and again. Processing can be embedded into [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) and [AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) with the help of embedding PApplet.

It is given in *[Class PApplet](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html)*. But I want to create GUI in Java FX. How could I embed PApplet into Java FX?

The part in Processing is the hardware interface which uses Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Issue noLoop(), and make the UI only call redraw() on user events (keyboard input, mouse movement, etc). Now it doesn't redraw "over and over" but only when it needs to.

Comment: I guess u must read this page : http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html
It clearly says that u shouldn't use swing components in PApplet.. Instead should embed it in swing..
But java fx gives better look then swing.. So i wanna know if i could embed PApplet in java fx..

Comment: right, which is why you want to do it the other way around. You write a Java application that uses Processing as a graphics library, and you tell your extension on PApplet to run noLoop() in its setup method. Then you tell it to update only when you need it to, based on your own UI elements (make your PApplet extension a listener for these UI elements). You don't use plain Java components in a Processing sketch, that's asking for a lot of problems. Stick with the full JVM.

Comment: Ohkie.. So JVM is better to use then Java fx according to u... Right??

Comment: Could you exactly tell me on how to do it??
Because am new to it..
If you could provide me any reference or help regarding how to use PApplet in Java fx..
Because in netbeans when i make a java fx project it uses a java fx platform, where in i could not use run the same code in PApplet which i was running in processing..
It instead uses Java fx syntax..